# emacs goto-line quits instead of going to a line

Tags: emacs, terminal

I'm trying to use the `goto-line` function in Emacs.

I have verified that my emacs belives <kbd>C-g g</kbd> OR <kbd>C-g C-g</kbd> is the goto-line command. However when I input <kbd>C-g</kbd> the status bar (on the bottom) Emacs quits and the next value I enter is typed into the file rather than into the status bar. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In my Emacs, `goto-line` is on `M-g g` and `M-g M-g`. (That is, Meta instead of Control.) `C-g` is usually bound to `keyboard-quit`, which used to cancel a command.

Comment: Just do C-h k  and then enter whatever the key you are trying to find the command.  For example:  C-h k M-g g.   Or you can do C-h f  goto-line to find the key for the command.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are mistaken that Emacs says that `goto-line` is bound to `C-g g` and `C-g C-g`.  What makes you think that?

It is also very unlikely that that would be the case, unless you went out of your way to try to create such key bindings.

The standard bindings for `goto-line` are `M-g g` and `M-g M-g`.  And `C-g` is bound by default (and should remain so) to `keyboard-quit`, which behaves as you describe.

Sounds like you are confusing the Meta key (typically your keyboard <kbd>Alt</kbd> key) with the Control key (typically your keyboard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key).

If your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key acts as a Meta key, then press and hold it while hitting the <kbd>g</kbd> key, to get `M-g`. Then hit `g` (or `M-g`) again, to get `goto-line`.

If your <kbd>Alt</kbd> key does not act as a Meta key then you can use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key instead: `ESC g g` should give you `goto-line`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify again with <kbd>M-x describe-key</kbd>? Usually <kbd>C-g</kbd> is the command `'keyboard-quit`, not a keymap (a key can be either a command or the first key of a combination, not both)